# Exponential family canonical form

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I cannot figure this myself - suppose I have some distribution $f(y; \theta)$ from the exponential family. By Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family) let us assume this form:

$
f(y; \theta) = h(y)exp\big[\eta(\theta)T(y) - A(\theta)\big]
$

The wiki defines the canonical form as

> If $\eta(\theta) = \theta$, then the exponential family is said to be
>   in canonical form

Then, it adds the part I do not get:

> By defining a transformed parameter $\eta(\theta) = \theta$, it is
>   always possible to convert an exponential family to canonical form

I do not get what they do with parameters $\theta$. For example, let us have the Normal with unknown mean $\mu$ AND unknown variance $\sigma^2$. There is immediately example in wiki, where they define:

$\eta = \big(\frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}, -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\big)$

and then conclude: then our form is canonical. Why is that? They initially define the normal as $f(y; \mu, \sigma)$! According to the previous definition, it is clear that $\eta(\theta) \neq (\mu, \sigma^2)$! Why do they call it a canonical form then?

Actually this can be shown almost for all distributions when written in  canonical form, their parameter vector $\eta$ is clearly not equal to the parameters in the definition.

Could someone clarify please.

Comment: It's a typo. They define $\theta=(\cdot,\cdot)^{\top}$ (look at the next lines where they define $A(\eta)$).

Comment: Then does it mean that the real density should be defined as $f(y; \frac{\mu}{\sigma^2}, -\frac{1}{2\sigma^2})$? They kinda no where mention that parameters can be swapped like that (apart from second quote "By defining a transformed parameter..." - which i did not get - is it what it implies?).